# Check if the first letter of each element of an array is capital using filter method. But I keep getting the whole array

Tags: javascript

```
// JavaScript Document
"use strict";
var testArray =["beau","Diane","morgan","Brittany"];
function checkCapital(value,index,array) {
    if(value!==value.charAt(0).toLowerCase())
    return value;
}
var capital =testArray.filter(checkCapital);
console.log(capital);
```

I need to check if the first letter of every value of the array is a capital  using filter method. But I keep getting the whole array returned on my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are comparing an entire string with the lowercase equivalent of its first character, which is a problem. And you are going to return `undefined` when your condition is not satisfied, and a specific character if it is, which is a little strange. Your filter function should be

```
return value.charAt(0) !== value.charAt(0).toLowerCase()
```

or use the more modern

```
return value[0] !== value[0].toLowerCase()
```

and write the whole app in more modern JavaScript as follows:

```
const testArray = ["beau", "Diane", "morgan", "Brittany", "^&#SYMBOLS$$--"];
const capital = testArray.filter(s => s[0] !== s[0].toLowerCase());
console.log(capital);
```

but really, what is and is not an uppercase letter is an interesting problem in its own right. What if a word starts with a comma? A Cherokee or Devanagari letter? Letter-like symbols? If you *really* want to do uppercase properly, you might want to get a package like [xregexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp) then you can write a filter function that matches `XRegExp("^\\p{Lu}")`. I understand this might be beyond what you are looking for at the moment, but it's a good thing to know about.

Comment: Great answer.Thank you so much Ray this worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` method depends on the `return` statement of the callback, which if returns `true` then `filter()` will include the current value to the array it will return. Just remove your `if` statement and put the condition on the `return` statement:

```
function checkCapital(value,index,array) {
    return value !== value.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
}
```

Because your original callback returns `true` always, it would include all elements of the original array to be returned by the `filter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First off you are always returning `value` from your filter function, that is the core reason why you are getting the whole array. A filter function shold return true or false depending on whether the value should or should not be included in the output.

You have other issues with your code but try and solve them on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
solution :- 





function checkUppercase(arr)
{
  var array1 = arr.split(' ');
  var newarray1 = [];
    
  for(var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++){
      newarray1.push(array1[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+array1[x].slice(1));
  }
   newarray1.join(' ');
   let i=0;
   if(JSON.stringify(array1) == JSON.stringify(newarray1)) {
       return true
   }else {
       return false;
   }
}
console.log(checkUppercase("solid Is Transparent"));
```